# Questions about van Kampen's theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, algebraic-topology

I just read some things about van Kampen's theorem that threat this one from a different perspective than we discussed in class and this brought up a few questions:

It was said that the images of the canonical embedding $\pi_1(X_1) \rightarrow \pi_1(X_1 \cup X_2)$ and $\pi_1(X_2) \rightarrow \pi_1(X_1 \cup X_2)$ completely define the fundamental group $\pi_1(X_1 \cup X_2)$? Why is this so? Why do these two subgroups completely define $\pi_1(X_1 \cup X_2)$?

I noticed when we were threating fundamental polygons that you can easily read off [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_polygon#Examples)  this $ABAB$ stuff and so on that you also find in this wikipedia reference. Now, I was wondering whether this is somehow related to the free product of groups that shows up in the context of van Kampen's theorem?

Comment: The images generate all of $\pi_1(X)$ because every path drawn in $X$ is homotopic to a concatenation of paths drawn in $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Comment: ah okay, but this could be infinitely many paths right? so this path could jump between $X_1$ and $X_2$.(Image that $X_1$ are the irrations on $[0,1]$ and $X_2$ the rationals. so now you take a path in $X$ that is just the straight line from ${0}$ to ${1}$. I think it is not that obvious that there is a homotopic(!) concatenation of paths in both subspaces.

Comment: You only need finitely many paths, because of compactness of $[0,1]$.

Comment: I don't understand the claim being made here. Take the unit circle $S^1$ and cover it by two open sets, each contractible to a point (e.g. the left and right semi-circles, each enlarged by $\epsilon$). Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be these two open sets, so that $X_1 \cup X_2 = S^1$. Then $\pi_1(X_1) = \pi_1(X_2) = 0$ but $\pi_1 (S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$. How is the fundamental group of $S^1$ determined by the fundamental groups of $X_1$ and $X_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear about language, the maps $\pi_1 (X_i) \to \pi_1(X_1 \cup X_2)$ ($i=1,2$) are not necessarily injections, but rather homomorphisms induced by the embeddings $ X_i \hookrightarrow X_1 \cup X_2$. As mentioned above, the images of these homomorphisms generate $\pi_1(X_1 \cup X_2)$. The kernels of these homomorphisms describe the ways in which loops in $X_1$ and loops in $X_2$ "interact".

Regarding fundamental polygons, the "words" such as $ABAB$ can be interpreted through free products of groups in some sense. A word $ABAB$ represents a relation in the group $G=\langle A,B : ABAB=1 \rangle$, i.e. the free group on letters $A$ and $B$ quotiented out by the subgroup generated by $ABAB$. This group can also be viewed as a free product of two groups, $G_A = \langle A \rangle$ and $G_B= \langle B\rangle$, amalgamated over the subgroup $\langle ABAB\rangle$. However, with fundamental polygons, these relations arise from identification of edges.  When applying Van Kampen's theorem, the relations arise from inclusions of loops in $X_1$ and $X_2$ into the intersection $X_1 \cap X_2$.